# WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path

Tags: python, google-api, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, traceback

Every time I run my python algorithm I am getting this error in cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "newScrape.py", line 1, in <module>
import SScraper as SS
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\SScraper\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.43.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\chrome\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.43.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\chrome\service.py", line 68, in start
and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable
needs to be available in the path.                 Please download from http://
chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html                and read up at htt
p://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

Here is my enviroment path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\; C:\FILES\chromedriver.exe;

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `C:\FILES\chromedriver.exe` with just `C:\FILES` since the `PATH` environment variable contains the semi-colon separated list of *directories*.

Comment: Thanks man, its changed now but I am still getting the same error.. I have been playing around with it all day different combinations and reboots etc

Comment: @ConnorStansfield ok, not sure if it matters, but omit the trailing `;` and the space before the `C:\FILES`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\FILES\

Comment: @ConnorStansfield ok, I'm assuming that didn't help. What if you explicitly specify the `executable_path` while instantiating the driver: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\FILES\chromedriver.exe')`?

Comment: I tried it again and now it has started working haha thanks alot! =]